# How to move an entire div element up x pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I want to reposition an entire div and its contents up about 10-15 pixels.

How can I do this?

Note:  this is slider element, so when I click a button the slider slides down.  Once it is finished I want to reposition it up about 15 pixels.

Comment: You should mention whether or not it currently has any positioning CSS. That way you might be able to alter it (e.g. with javascript).

Comment: Have you considered `position: relative; top: -15px;`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
$('#div_id').css({marginTop: '-=15px'});
```

This will alter the css for the element with the id "div_id"

To get the effect you want I recommend adding the code above to a callback function in your animation (that way the div will be moved up after the animation is complete):

```
$('#div_id').animate({...}, function () {
    $('#div_id').css({marginTop: '-=15px'});
});
```

And of course you could animate the change in margin like so:

```
$('#div_id').animate({marginTop: '-=15px'});
```

Here are the docs for `.css()` in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/css/

And here are the docs for `.animate()` in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @Kira The `duration` argument can be passed after the `properties` argument. It should be an integer and defaults to `400`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's a bad idea to animate `margin` property, because it changes the elements layout and causes reflow. The much better idea would be to use `transform-translate` property for animation with CSS transition.

Answer (score 50):

```
$('div').css({
    position: 'relative',
    top: '-15px'
});
```

Answer (score 14):

In css add this to the element:

```
margin-top: -15px; /*for exact positioning */
margin-top: -5%; /* for relative positioning */
```

you can use either one to position accordingly.

Comment: This method works best, if you want to use only CSS

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
margin-top:-30px; 
min-height:40px;
```

this "help" to stop the div yanking everything up a bit.